# ASP.NET as server app - questions before I'm getting into it

Tags: asp.net

Earlier on I've implemented a custom C++ server from scratch, something which is nice and fun to do but is very time-consuming.

So I've heard about "servlet" of Java which sounds like something I'm looking for for my next project.

I'm looking at ASP.NET to be used as a servlet because it's pretty much mature in terms of networking capabilities and programming features and I can write code for it in C# which is a language I already know and feels good with.

Anyway before getting into it I'd like to get concise answers regarding some of the capabilities that ASP.NET may provide me with.
My client application is Flash-based and has nothing to do with XML or HTTP protocols (raw sockets).

**1) Can I accept raw** (in terms of protocol) **socket connections** and **keep them alive** as long as needed?
**2)** How hard/complicated is it to **apply AES encryption** over a connected socket?
**3)** Can I have a **"shared", in-memory, objects**, like lists, **over the application's instance**?
**4)** Can I get one message from client X and send a copy/reply/report (on the fly) to client Y, without using a database or anything like that? This question suggests question #5.
**5)** Can I identify a connection by its memory address or object address, so I can refer to it directly?
**6)** Can my application be distributed over several servers?
**7)** How hard/complicated is it to **scale such an application**? For 10 concurrent connections there's no problem but for 50,000 I can surely expect load issues.
**8)** Finally, the most important question which probably has the most complex answer: **How flexible is the environment from a programmer perspective?** I mean, can I control events such as "on_connect", "on_disconnect" and stuff like that? How hard would it be to **access connection Y from connection X's event (such as "on_data_received")?**

Comment: No answer nor comment after 5 hours on such a subject? I must be hallucinating!

Comment: Even experts need holiday sometimes.. ;)

Comment: Right, they do, but it's a fact that I'm here and therefore it's not the time for an holiday (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net is more like JSP than Java Servlets as it requires a web server to run.  Typically IIS is used since Microsoft has built in ASP.Net support there, but it's possible to run ASP.Net on other web servers. As a web server product it's all HTTP and therefor connectionless. Based on your questions 1, 2, 4, 5 and 8 this may be a deal-killer for you.

If you can code your Flash application to manage itself with HTTP/HTTPS connections then using ASP.Net to build out web services that your app can use is a decent option. IIS is mature and can scale out nicely (q's 6 & 7).  It also has an application-level store that you can use (q3). Of course each server in a farm would have its own copy.

It's possible to implement your own server in C# with a lot less effort than in C++, but it's still a time consuming endeavor. The TcpListener class in System.Net.Sockets would be the starting point if you chose to go that route.

Comment: Nice website that's one - liked the password & toothbrush quote (: Well, I hope someone comes up with a solution for the "deal-killer" questions.. or SO allow me to put a bounty, this question worth a lot. Regarding writing a server in C# - why would I do that, if I already got one with C++? I'm trying to shorten the work..

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Client/Server .NET application, not ASP.NET as it's out of its "scope".

Unless one of the demands is to have public website?

Comment: Yup, there's pretty much a demand to have it done through a solid sockets framework such as a website service (IIS..). The website would also suppport SSL naturally, which is highly desired.

Comment: SSL is good point, however sockets are not part of ASP.NET just part of the .NET framework in general.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me from which part sockets are as long as the connected client is connected, and secured (SSL), something that IIS takes care of.

Comment: Actually when working with web application, the client has no "live" connection with the server. It can interact with the server only by sending requests. You sure that's what you want?

Comment: Of course not. I want a persistent connection with the server with asymmetric (full-duplex) data transfer.. I know that Java Servlet do something similar.